# Do I need to instantiate Database Service in every Page of Ionic 2 Application

Tags: ionic2, pouchdb

I am using PouchDB with Ionic 2 in Typescript.

```
initDB(){
    console.log("Initialising the DB");
    this._db = new PouchDB('mydb', {adapter:'websql'});
  }
```

Do I have to run this piece of code while instantiating Individual PageClasses Everytime?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a global service for the db.Though havent used pouchDB in particular.
You could initialize the db in provider constructor.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class DBProvider {
 _db:any;

  constructor() {
  this._db = new PouchDB('mydb', {adapter:'websql'});
  }
...
}
```

Set the class as the provider in your app.module.ts